# In DPI-C, what data types to be used for internal variables?

Tags: c, system-verilog, system-verilog-dpi

I am not getting correct output for the following piece of code using DPI-C in VCS in EDA Playground. I expect 6 as answer but I get 248 every time, irrespective of a and b values. I have tried using svLogic, int and unsigned char for data type for a_int in helloFromC.c.

```
module automatic test;

  import "DPI-C" function void helloFromC(logic [2:0] a, logic [2:0] b);

  initial run();

  task run();
    logic [2:0] a; 
    logic [2:0] b; 
    logic [2:0] c;
    a = 3'b100;
    b = 3'b010;
    c = a+b;
    $display("Output from SV is %0d", c);
    helloFromC(a,b);

  endtask

endmodule
```

This is my C program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <svdpi.h>


extern "C" int helloFromC(svLogic a, svLogic b) {
  svLogic a_int = a+b;
  printf("Output from C is %d", a_int);
  return 0;
}
```

I get output as

```
Output from SV is 6
Output from C is 248
```

Comment: From the `svdpi.h` header it looks like `svLogic` is an `uint8_t`. If so, that doesn't match the "%d" format string in C.

Comment: `logic` is a 4-state variable. Try `bit`. Also since you use 3-bit vars, mask the m in 'c'/

Comment: @Serge I did not get what you meant by "mask the m in 'c' "

Comment: I have also tried with format specifier %u, %uhh. it still get 248

Comment: instead of 'logic' try 'bit' in verilog and 'int' in c instead of svLogic. As for masking do `a_int = (a & 0x7) + (b & 0x7)`

Comment: I am getting `Output from C is 0` now

Comment: Only correct output is when a and b are declared as byte in SV and svBit in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svLogic` is supposed to map to a single bit `logic`. You have a vector (aka packed array), therefor you should be using `svLogicVecVal`. It is still a 4-state value, so algorithmic operations of SystemVerilog values performed on the C side may not work the way you expect. Using `bit [2:0]` on the SystemVerilog side and `svBitVecVal` on the C side will work more as you expect. Or simplify things and use `int` on both sides.

For more on DPI, refer to [IEEE1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) section 35, Annex H, and Annex I.

Comment: Is it svLogicVecValue or svLogicVecVal? Also, Im getting an error: error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'svLogicVecVal {aka vpi_vecval}' and 'svLogicVecVal {aka vpi_vecval}')
   svLogicVecVal a_int = a+b;

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji it is `svLogicVecVal`. I fixed the typo. It is a struct type defined in Annex H.10.1.2. If the operator+ is not defined for this type, then you will either need to define it yourself (search for "C custom operator" an "C overload operator"), or directly access the struct items in your operation.

Comment: from what I searched, I got results that C operators can be custom or overload. If there's an example, that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

From one of the links, [addition using DPI call](https://geekwentfreak-raviteja.rhcloud.com/blog/2014/06/20/passing-and-receiving-different-systemverilog-datatypes-with-cc-using-dpi/)I could find what I was looking for

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <svdpi.h>


extern "C" void
add_bpv(
    const svBitVecVal* a,
    const svBitVecVal* b,
    svBitVecVal* c) {
    *c = *a + *b;
    printf("Output from C is %d", *c);
}
```

And now the SV program DPI call

```
module automatic test;

  import "DPI-C" function void add_bpv(input bit [3:0] a,b, output bit [3:0] c);

  initial run();

  task run();
    bit [3:0] a,b,c;
    a = 3'b100;
    b = 3'b010;
    c = a+b;
    $display("Output from SV is %d", c);
    add_bpv(a,b,c);
  endtask

endmodule
```

The output is what I wanted

```
Output from SV is  6
Output from C is 6
```

Comment: Well if it is solving my question, then yes :D